# Can I set Gradle and Maven to install their local repos in other dir than %userprofile% in Windows?

Tags: windows, maven, gradle, build, dependency-management

The question is about these build tools themeselves. How can I set the directory (local-repo) where they can chache dependencies? The default is to the user home, under the .gradle/ or .m2e/ subdirectories.

1. %userprofile% Windows
2. $HOME Linux

How can I change these defaults?

Comment: @Asettouf thanks but that would be pointing my build to another repo. What I want is that my gradle and maven tools place their local repo in other dir than the mentioned in the question

Comment: Then I really don't understand your requirement, because from what I understand, you want to change the location of where dependencies are stored, and that's the way with Maven (sorry I don't know much about Gradle). If you don't believe me, check the documentation in my edit

Comment: @Asettouf You are wright about maven. Sorry about that, I did not read your answer very well. At first I thougth it was a setting in a pom file. Thx that is what i wanted about maven, im looking for the same for gradle with no luck

Comment: Im wondering if it is possible to share de java local repo between gradle and maven. Sometimes it can get to 4GB. I will give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MAVEN** -

Correctly pointed by @Asettouf, you can customize the `settings.xml` for maven to include the following -

```
<settings>
  ...
  <localRepository>/custom/path</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

---

**GRADLE** -

You can use either of the followings -

Set the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable,

```
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/custom/path
```

Or set `gradle.user.home` system property as -

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Dgradle.user.home=/custom/path
```

Or `--gradle-user-home` command line parameter.

```
gradle --gradle-user-home=/custom/path -d
```

Comment: It is also possible to do this on command line via: `mvn -D-Dmaven.repo.local=PathWhichYouLIkeToHave`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Maven in your *settings.xml* file you can define a different directory with:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html for more configuration options